# Unknown Coordinate system for San Francisco LiDAR LAS Files! How it is possible to assign a coordinate system to LAS file?

Tags: arcgis-pro, lidar

I have downloaded all the publicly available LiDAR data from https://viewer.nationalmap.gov/basic/ for San Francisco area. Files cannot be converted since the coordinate system is unknown in all the data covering at least the Berkeley area.

[image]

How I can assign the coordinate system (which theoretically is not possible because I have to first convert them and then assign the coordinate system) or solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using LP360 which is a software for manipulating LiDAR data (suggested by a professor (thank you Dr.Jensen)). I just imported the files in LP360 and exported them as LAS files and did not change anything. The program takes care of everything!

However, I believe that the problem was caused by the different projection I was using in my project. Even after switching to Albers, files were falling in Canada. I simply re-downloaded them again and opened a new project, set the map projection to Albers, and then added the LAS files, and this time they were shown in the right place.

So, basically, there are 3 ways to solve this problem:2 are mentioned above, and one is to use the Laszip program.

Answer (score 1):

- Use the Create LAS Dataset(Data Management) tool to define projection to the LAS file.

[image]

- Kindly follow this link([Create a LAS dataset](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/data/las-dataset/create-a-las-datasets.htm)) for a better understanding.

Comment: Thank you but actually, it is not possible to add the input because the files are in LAZ format and when I try to convert them I get the coordinate system error!

Comment: You know what? I was able to convert LAZs files using LASzip tool. I also created the LAS dataset and forced the Lambert Conformal Conic as the coordinate system but the Files are falling in Graham Island and not Berkeley. I am going to play with the coordinate system and will update this thread soon!

Comment: I was not able to relocate the LAS file to the correct position which must be Berkeley area. Either I am doing something wrong or the original data is wrongly geocoded! I have changed the coordinate system/ tried projected ones/ but still, it does not match the correct position.